# Make second api call after first api call returns data

Tags: reactjs, api, async-await, react-context

I'm having a hard time with this and I can't seem to get my head around it.

At the moment I have two api's. One that gets fetched via a subdomain prefix and then another api call,  that requires the subdomain prefix, that fetches some data which will be needed to fetch the next api call. In this case the `id` of the subdomain prefix fetched data. Here's an example:

When you load `https://<name>.mywebsite.com` we use the  `name` prefix to fetch first data which  gives me back an  object about the subdomain. In this case, the name, id, logo etc.

Once that's been loaded, I need to then fetch some data on a different api call, which requires a subdomain id. In this case `/api/<subdomainId>/`.

As you can see it requires data from the first api fetch to then make the next api fetch.

I'm currently using React context:

```
  // Get subdomain and store it in a state subdomain: {}
  const getSubdomain = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`https://api.mywebsite.com/api/v1/subdomain`);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SUBDOMAIN,
        payload: res.data
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

then my next method is:

```
  // Get posts (from storedomain: { id: 1 }
  const getPosts = async() => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `https://api.mywebsite.com/api/v1/public/${state.subdomain.id}/posts`
        );

        dispatch({
          type: GET_IDEAS,
          payload: res.data.rows
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
  };
```

This unfortunately gives me a null error for subdomain.id as it's not waiting until subdomain object has finished fetching. I tried playing with useEffect, but I'm having no luck. I was wondering if there is a clean way of doing this and  making it dynamic, vs having to pass in the `subdomain.id` via a useEffect. The posts would then be added into a `posts: {}` object once its fetched.

I apologise in advance if I'm not making any sense. I'll try clarify any other concerns.

Comment: In my opinion the best way to achieve that is using promises. axios.get(...).then(response => { axios.get(...)}

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining the async requests together. Something along the lines of:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  const subdomain = await fetchSubdomain()
  dispatch(/* subdomain */)
  const posts = await fetchPosts(subdomain)
  dispatch(/* posts */)
}
```

Note that `fetchSubdomain` and `fetchPosts` are slightly different from the code examples you gave. They just wrap `axios.get(...)`.